# How to call Dynamic Value from JavaScript in Paw?

Tags: paw-app

How do you call HMac-Sha1 in a custom extension javascript? I need to generate a custom signature for my RESTful API.

I need to call a dynamic value from the JavaScript call using the [Paw JS API](https://luckymarmot.com/paw/doc/Extensions/Reference). For instance, I need to compute an HMAC + SHA1 hash from my JS code, and for that I thought it would be convenient to use the existing "HMAC-SHA1" dynamic value.

How do I do that?

Answer (score 0):

You can do it by instantiating a new `DynamicValue` setting its values, wrap it in a `DynamicString` and evaluate it.

*Note, the dynamic values themselves aren't documented yet. But you have the doc of [`DynamicValue`](https://luckymarmot.com/paw/doc/Extensions/Reference/DynamicValue) and [`DynamicString`](https://luckymarmot.com/paw/doc/Extensions/Reference/DynamicString).*

Here's the code:

```
function evaluate(context){

    // create a dynamic value of that type
    var dv = DynamicValue('com.luckymarmot.HMACDynamicValue');

    // set its properties 
    dv.algorithm = 1; // (not documented) algorithm = 1 for SHA1
    dv.input = "Something to Hash"; // input string
    dv.key = "HASH_KEY"; // HMAC key

    // wrap in a (dynamic) string
    var string = DynamicString(dv)

    // evaluate the string
    return string.getEvaluatedString();
};
```